# Best way to store profile property type data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I'm approaching a new project and would love some advice to prevent future regrets. I'll use a user profile for an example and will keep each method basic for point of explanation.

Approach One:

Creating a table with multiple columns:

```
UserProfile: UserID, Firstname, Lastname, Birthdate, Address, City, State, Zipcode, Bio
```

Approach Two:

Building a relationship based system:

```
Table1: ProfileItems ( ProfileID, ProfileName, DataType )
Table2: UserProfile ( UserID, ProfileID, ProfileValue )
```

Approach One is obvious in its usage.

Approach Two Scenario:

User goes to edit their profile and haven't filled out their address yet.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT UserID FROM UserProfile WHERE UserID = @UserID AND ProfileValue = 'Address')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO... etc.
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE...
    END
```

Which method would be more efficient for scalability? Method two I can build an admin application that allows a user to create profile types without having to alter a table in SQL. Would future queries of this data be more intensive? Like displaying the user's profile page and having to query each one? Or perhaps I would create a custom view to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about directly

```
Table: UserProfile ( UserID, ProfileName, ProfileValue )
```

And the datatype of ProfileName, ProfileValue both are "string". Then "User" and "UserProfile" can work for user profile and be scalable. The type conversion could be done in the program using the DB table.

Comment: I was hoping for clarity of performance. Is it better to store the data in rows only when they exist? Or to have a single table with columns and empty or null value when the user hasn't filled out that information yet?

Comment: I think usually fetch data from one table should have a much better performance than join 2 or 3 tables to get information.